# Flag duplicates in MySQL select query output

Tags: mysql, duplicates

My sql query so far has a few joins on tables and the final output looks like this:

```
FLAG        id      name
----        ---     ----
OK          21      ken
OK          34      mon
OK          51      jil
OK          51      jil
OK          71      jil
OK          80      ron
OK          91      ron
```

Now I want the FLAGs of duplicate names be shown as 'dup' of the lowest id:

```
FLAG        id      name
----        ---     ----
OK          21      ken
OK          34      mon
OK          51      jil
dup_51      51      jil
dup_51      71      jil
OK          80      ron
dup_80      91      ron
```

I can do it by using shell/perl script on the records stored in a file, but need to know if it can be possible by manipulating my SQL query.. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: this is rather non-trivial. any reason you have to do it sql-side rather than in the client?

Comment: you need to have a unique row ID for every row, even dupes.  then you select min(rowID) for every unique composite of id and name, and update that rowID as OK, everything else as dupe

Comment: if you want to do it in mysql, check user defined variables and case staments..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a subquery that tracks duplicate entries on `name` and returns the minimum `id` for each duplicate. I'll asume your table is named `tbl`:

```
select name, min(id) as dupId
from tbl
group by name
having count(name) > 1
```

Now you can join this with your original table:

```
select 
    tbl.*, if(not isnull(dupId), 'Ok', concat('dup_', dupId)) as flag2
from 
    tbl
    left join (
        select name, min(id) as dupId
        from tbl
        group by name
        having count(name) > 1) as a on tbl.name = a.name
```

This is a way to do it. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for this. I, however, did this in a shell script: processed the old output file line by line and compared with the prev line.

Comment: @Drek well.. that was the best solution anyway (just like Mark B commented)... however, if you need to do it *inside* mysql, you need to use some subquery. happy to help